# What is the Timeline for the Active Version Pie Chart in the Repository?

Tags: plugin-development, statistics, repository

When going through your own plugin details and checking the active version downloads. It's helpful to see which version that webmasters prefer, but I see no details on the subject on WordPress (and on here, yet). I recently had an unexpected change in stats, and I can't find anything as to what the time frame is. What few that I have found are either closed with little or no response, and/or indirectly related.

The active version pie chart can be found on any plugin under **Stats**.

```
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/[PLUGIN-NAME]/stats/
```

Most of the time, new versions don't even show up until about a day or so, but is the timeline based on days, weeks, or months?

This says that it is based on the current active users. Which is interesting.
[Daily Tip: New Usage Graphs on WordPress.org Plugin Repository](http://wpmu.org/daily-tip-new-usage-graphs-on-wordpress-org-plugin-repository/)

Any additional information on how the chart actually works is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The active version pie chart is made up of completely nonsense data that isn't being updated properly at present. What it displays has absolutely no bearing to real-world data.

It's on my list of things-to-fix, eventually. Once our stats gathering system is more reliable, I'll do so.

However, at present, it is total nonsense. Ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it would be great to get more stats .. As it stands total downloads is a number but active users is shown as a pie graph. I'd rather it the other way.

After reading wrox publishers professional wordpress plugin book, I found that each day every install of wordpress will check for plugin updates and send back info on what plugins are installed.

So I can't answer your question directly ... But it seems there is a delay in processing the plugin usage data

To be clear the downloads stats is each day, past 7 days and total downloads.